# Bootstrap dropdown not working asp.net mvc BundleConfig.cs

Tags: javascript, html

```
# Dropdown Button not working #
```

> I Added my all BundleConfig files(jquery,bootstrap) but My dropdrown button not working .
>   I'm trying change my users Authority with dropdown button. Other bootstrap element's working good.
>   But my dropdrown button not working. I tried cdn bootstrap and jquery library its working . but my 
>       bundle config not working.

'Index.cshtml'

```
@using System.Web.Optimization

@model IEnumerable<SehirRehberi.Models.SehirRehberi>

 @{
  Layout = null;
 }

 <html>
 <head>
   <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    table tbody th {
        width: 10px;
    }
</style>
@Styles.Render("~/styles")
@Styles.Render("~/scripts")

</head>
<body>
<br><br><br>
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <h3 class="display-4" style="font-style:italic; color:white;">Şehir Rehberi</h3>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
  target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria- 
 label="Toggle 
 navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
         </button>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
             <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                 <li class="nav-item active">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                         Anasayfa
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Eklenmiş Şehirler</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kullanıcılar</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<!-- Navigation -->
<br><br>

<!-- Modal Popup -->


<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title display-5">{{KullanıcıAdı}} Düzenleme</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input type="" class="form-control" name="" placeholder="Kullanıcı Adı">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input type="" class="form-control" name="" placeholder="E-mail Adresi">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning">Yetkiyi Değiştir</span> <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Admin
                            </button>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Editör</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Kullanıcı</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Yetkiyi Dondur</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal Popup -->
<!-- /.container -->

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h5 class="display-5"><span style="font-style: italic;"><u>Yönetim Paneli</u></span></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h5><button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Kullanıcı Ekle</button></h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr style="background-color: gray; color: white;">
                    <th scope="col"></th>
                    <th scope="col">Kullanıcı</th>
                    <th scope="col">Yetkisi</th>
                    <th scope="col">Durumu</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col"><i class="fas fa-user-shield"></i></th>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" style="color: black" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">
                                @item.AdminUserName
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">@item.Authority</span>
                        </td>
                        <td><span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">@item.Status</span></td>
                    }


                </tr>


            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/scripts")
@RenderSection("Scripts", false)
```

```
'BundleConfig.cs'

using Microsoft.Web.Optimization;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace SehirRehberi.App_Start
{
 public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(System.Web.Optimization.BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/styles")
              .Include("~/content/css/bootstrap.css")
              .Include("~/content/css/bootstrap.min.css")
              .Include("~/content/css/all.css")

              );
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scripts")
          .Include("~/content/js/bootstrap.js")
          .Include("~/content/js/bootstrap.min.js")
          .Include("~/content/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js")
          .Include("~/content/js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js")
          .Include("~/content/js/popper.min.js")
          .Include("~/content/js/all.js")
           ) ;

    }
}
```

}